# Dynamic description in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to set up a form that can be reused monthly. Questions will be the same from month to month, but with different focus. For instance, a question is named "Marketing". In October I want the description say "Focus on product group A" and in November "Focus on product group B". All questions are of the type "Paragraph".

Is there a way to do this? It would also work with automatic population of fields when opening the form.

I could manually change this every month but there will be about 15 forms to keep the answers in different docs. So population from a sheet would be nifty.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include a built-in feature to achieve the desired result but you could add it by using add-ons either for Google Sheets or for Google Forms. Another option is to use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start).

To ask for add-ons recommendations you could make a question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

References

- [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)