# Show number of responses in Google Form to people filling the form

Tags: google-forms

I would like to know if there is a way to add to the form something like "X people filled the form" for people other than me. The option to show the summary of responses gives too much information so I would not like to use that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically retrieve and display data based on input from google forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88837/how-to-dynamically-retrieve-and-display-data-based-on-input-from-google-forms)

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. It IS possible to identify the number of responses (say, `var respNum = form.getResponses().length`). The challenge is to find a field/location where this value can be displayed AND will be dynamically updated after every response. The topic of dynamic fields is very popular and the answer tends to be "presently, there is no such thing.

Comment: Related: [Dynamic description in Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/113210/196152)